# Aluminum window trim: what is it called and where to look for it?

Tags: windows, trim, aluminum

I am building a wall in my condo. To place the stud as close to the window frame as possible, I had to cut through the rectangular enclosure (that houses a power cable) made of plywood and covered by 1/16" aluminum.

This aluminum trim/shield was glued into the flooring so I had to use force to remove it. I twisted it in the process. I would like to buy it new but I am not sure what it's called and where to look for it. Any ideas?

I also need something very similar to finish off (or cap) the wall (both the stud and the sheet rock) where it meets the window.

[image: Window]
[image: smaller piece]
[image: smaller piece 1]
[image: bigger piece]

Comment: Please check the inside of the windows for any maker's names, bar codes, or other hints as to who made it.

Comment: @Bryce: nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like powdercoated steel.  In that size, you probably will have to get something custom made.  You can try to source the raw powdercoated steel yourself online (or locally?) and have a professional shape it for you.  If you are lucky you might find some pre-bent 90 degree stock online as well.

Here's one possible one-stop shop, but it might be pricey.  Be careful to match the sheen to your existing metal! http://www.rapidsheetmetal.com/powder.aspx

I think you'd be best off finding a fab shop locally so you can bring your piece in and just have them duplicate it to your specs.